# Ant not excluding files from build

Tags: ant, build, tar

I'm currently building a tar:

```
<property name="dcc-shell.dir" value="."/>
<property name="dcc-mdp.dir" value="${dcc-shell.dir}/eq-mo-drop-copy-converter-mdp"/>
<property name="mdp-code.dir" value="${dcc-mdp.dir}/*"/>
<property name="mdp-exclude.dir" value="${dcc-mdp.dir}/target"/>
<property name="dcc-srv.dir" value="${dcc-shell.dir}/eq-mo-drop-copy-converter-server"/>
<property name="srv-code.dir" value="${dcc-srv.dir}/src/main/*"/>
<property name="dcc-trans.dir" value="${dcc-shell.dir}/eq-mo-drop-copy-converter-transformer"/>
<property name="trans-code.dir" value="${dcc-trans.dir}/src/main/*"/>

<target name="create MDP.Tar">
    <tar destfile="${dcc-shell.dir}/mdp.tar"
        excludes="${mdp-exclude.dir}"
        basedir="${dcc-mdp.dir}"
    />
</target>
```

however it continuly keeps adding the target file and it's contents to the tar file dispite specifying the it to be excluded via excludes=dir

Comment: What if you try excludes="${mdp-exclude.dir}/*" ?

Comment: You could also try a nested <fileset></fileset>, where you could explicitly add child <include/> and <exclude/> elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I found this to be a solution:
`**/target/**`

Comment: Can you please write complete corrected block of code. I am facing same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need the "**" to exclude the directory and everything in it. These `excludes` are file based and not directory based.

```
<target name="create MDP.Tar">
    <tar destfile="${dcc-shell.dir}/mdp.tar"
        excludes="${mdp-exclude.dir}/**"
        basedir="${dcc-mdp.dir}"
    />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your relative paths are off, your script is basically doing this:

Include all files from the directory:

```
./eq-mo-drop-copy-converter-mdp
```

but dont include this one:

```
./eq-mo-drop-copy-converter-mdp\target
```

Which really reads `eq-mo-drop-copy-converter-mdp/eq-mo-drop-copy-converter-mdp\target` which doesn't exist.

You need to specify exclude `.\target\**`

Comment: if that was the case then surely shouldn't ${dcc-mdp.dir}" not work?
 I gave it the definiative path. Still did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by definiative path?